Spell slots of a Sorlock multiclass
I'm playing as a Warlock 3/ Sorcerer 3 multiclass, which would make me a 6th-level spellcaster. So whenever I use a Warlock spell like Hex and don't want to upcast it, can I use my Sorcerer spell slots instead? And can I use 3rd level spell like Fireball? If so, whose spell slot would be used?

You are a 3rd level Spellcaster, and have 3rd level Pact Magic

... you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

So, yes, you can use a Sorcerer spell slot to cast a Warlock spell (at the spell slot's level) and a Warlock slot to cast a Sorcerer spell (at the highest level - in this case, 2nd). You need to keep track of which spell slots you have used separately.
How these combine is described in the Multiclass Spellcaster rules:

You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class.

As a 3rd-level Sorcerer, you cannot learn a 3rd-level spell like Fireball.
If, instead, you were a 3rd-level Sorcerer/3rd-level Cleric, both of which have the Spellcasting feature, you would have spells known/prepared for each class (maximum 2nd level for a 3rd-level Spellcaster) but have the spell slots of a 6th-level Spellcaster (which would include 3 3rd-level slots which you could use to upcast any of your 1st or 2nd-level spells).

Not directly related but probably useful addition: sorcerers can convert spell slots to sorcery points. They could convert the warlock spell slots (up to the maximum number of sorcery points) and then regain them after short rest. Since sorcerers can also convert sorcery points to slots, you could "transform" warlock slots to sorcerer slots. The "exchange rate" means you lose out some slot levels in the process: you can transform warlock level 3 slot to a sorcerer level 2 slot. But you can also transform a warlock level 3 slot to a sorcerer level 1 slot and have 1 sorcery point change, etc.

@VLAZ The multiclassing rules don't exactly allow you to do that. You explicitly can use warlock spell slots to cast non-warlock spells; using them for other non-warlock class features is not addressed.

@MarkWells that's not true: Can I use Pact Magic spell slots gained on a short rest to gain sorcery points? nowhere does the flexible casting feature specify you have to consume or create sorcerer spell slots. It just consumes or creates spell slots. It's just a bit of waste to use sorcery points to create warlock slots but it's possible. You may want to to activate some warlock feature (e.g., invocations) that specifically require a warlock spell slots. But you get better "exchange" trading warlock slots -> sorcery points -> (lower) sorcerer slot
